# What is the order of execution of Animate?

Tags: animation

I used to think the execution order of `Animate` is the same as `For` until I find:

```
Animate[var++,{n,0,10,1}];
```

the var increases while `n` not. But

```
Animate[var=n,{n,0,10,1}];
```

the `n` keeps increasing.

Why would this happen?

If I want a expression which don't contain n to be executed only once in every step, what should I do? (Actually, I want to embed a code in my website using `CDF`. It will be OK if there are other solutions without using `Animate`.)

Comment: You should initialize `var`, i.e., `var = 1; Animate[var++, {n, 0, 10, 1}]` works as exptected. Or, if you want to rest `var` in every cycle you can use `var = 1; Animate[Mod[var++, 10, 1], {n, 0, 10, 1}]`. Also look at [Clock](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clock.html), e.g. `Dynamic@Clock[{0, 10, 1}]`

Comment: @kguler It works as expected but is not what the OP wants? I think the OP already had initialized `var`, or he wouldn't have observed the behavior that he observed.

Comment: @Pickett, very good observation -- should have read the question carefully..

Comment: Does my answer address your question, or is there still some issue that needs explanation?

Comment: Never mind.  Just saw your comment. How funny -- at the same time! :)

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem

`Animate` returns a `Manipulate`:

```
Animate[var++, {n, 0, 9, 1}] // InputForm
(*
 Manipulate[
 var++,
 {{n, 1}, 0, 9, 1, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
    "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}},
 ControlType -> Animator, AppearanceElements -> None, 
 DefaultBaseStyle -> "Animate", DefaultLabelStyle -> "AnimateLabel", 
 SynchronousUpdating -> True, ShrinkingDelay -> 10.]
*)
```

`Manipulate` in turn wraps its body `var++` with `Dynamic`.  Thus the displayed expression depends on `var` and the body will be updated whenever `var` changes value.  Since evaluation leads to incrementing `var` each time, updating occurs as rapidly as possible.  Another issue, which might or might not be important, is that an `Animator` updates its variable `n` according to a [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clock.html).  This is so that equal changes in `n` occur in equal times.  It is not guaranteed to increment by `1` at each step, if the animation rate is relatively high.

#### Solutions

The desired behavior requires `var` to be incremented whenever `n` changes. One approach is to make the body depend on `n` but not on `var`.  [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) will help restrict dependency to explicitly listed symbols.

**Potentially buggy solutions**

The simplest approach is to add the expression `n;` to the body, and restrict the tracked symbols to `n`:

```
var = 0;
Animate[n; var++, {n, 0, 9, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {n}]
```

This will behave in the desired way on most or all computer systems.

The problem is that `n` will be incremented at a constant rate no matter how long it takes `n; var++` to execute and be redisplayed.  It is possible for `n` to be increased by more than `var`.  This can be observed in the following.  The `AnimationRate` might need to be adjusted for a particular computer.  On mine, the variables start to slip apart around a rate of `20` or `25` and constantly slip at a rate of `100`.

```
var = 0;
Animate[var++; {Mod[n - var, 10], n, var}, {n, 0, 9, 1}, 
 AnimationRate -> 100, TrackedSymbols :> {n}]
```

**Synchronized, but might not always be updated by one**

If the variables need to be synchronized, then the updating `var` at the same time as `n` is the way to go.  This can be done with the second argument of [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html).  Since `Animate` automatically sets up the control for `n`, I'll adapt the `Manipulate` code above to customize the `Animator` control.

```
var = 1;
Manipulate[
 {Mod[var - n, 10], n, var},
 {{n, var},
  Animator[Dynamic[n, (var += # - n; n = #) &],
    {0, 9, 1},
    AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
      "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}] &},
 AppearanceElements -> None, DefaultBaseStyle -> "Animate", 
 DefaultLabelStyle -> "AnimateLabel", SynchronousUpdating -> True, 
 ShrinkingDelay -> 10.]
```

**Synchronized, updated by one**

One can override the default update of `n` in the previous code to ensure that `n` and `var` are incremented by `1` each time.  This breaks the synchronization with `Clock` and the direction button of the `Animator`. (One probably ought to omit `"DirectionButton"` from `AppearanceElements`, but I'll leave it in so one can try it.)

```
var = 1;
Manipulate[
 {Mod[var - n, 10], n, var},
 {{n, var},
  Animator[Dynamic[n, (var++; n = Mod[n + 1, 10]) &],
    {0, 9, 1},
    AnimationRate -> 100,
    AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
      "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}] &},
 AppearanceElements -> None, DefaultBaseStyle -> "Animate", 
 DefaultLabelStyle -> "AnimateLabel", SynchronousUpdating -> True, 
 ShrinkingDelay -> 10.]
```

Comment: I changed `10` to `9` because I found it more convenient for `n` to take on ten different values.

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user18935 You're welcome.